# Finding $P(Y>X)$ from a joint density

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Question and my attempt is as follows.

[image: question and my attempt]

I integrated in terms of $x$ then $y$ but my value for $P(Y>X)> 1$ which does not make sense. I think my integration is correct but there is potentially an issue with the limits I have used causing $P(Y>X) > 1$. Found $k$ to be one here after integrating in terms of $x$ and $y$ from their respective limits.

Comment: $0<x<y$ **and** $x<1$. You cannot integrate w.r.t. $x$ from $0$ to $y$ for all $y$ from $0$ to $2$.

Comment: Is k not equal to 1? @lulu

Comment: Yes!  It is.  I just checked that, and have deleted my comment accordingly.

Comment: @geetha290krm how would I go about deciding the limits for x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The boundaries for your integral are not correct.

The region where $f$ is non-zero is rectangle $[0,1]\times [0,2]$ (more accurately, the segments should be open intervals, but it doesn't make a difference for integration and segments are more natural when integrating).

Since you want to find out $P(Y>X)$, you want subset of $[0,1]\times [0,2]$ consisting of all $(x,y)$ such that $y > x$, drawing a picture:

[image]

To write correct double integral for calculation, we have two natural choices.

1. The outer integral we'll be integrating with respect to $x$, and the inner with respect to $y$. So, we take full range of $x$, that is from $0$ to $1$. The region we are describing lies between lines $y = x$ and $y = 2$, so the $y$ goes from $x$ to $2$: $$P(Y>X) = \int_0^1\int_x^2xy\,dydx.$$

[image]

2. The outer integral we'll be integrating with respect to $y$, and the inner with respect to $y$. So, we take full range of $y$, that is from $0$ to $2$. However, it's more complicated to describe bounds for $x$, because our region is bound from left by the line $x = 0$, but from the right it's two lines, $x = y$ and $x = 1$, so we want to split our region in two parts. When $y$ is between $0$ and $1$, our region is between the lines $x = 0$ and $x = y$, and when $y$ is between $1$ and $2$, our region is between the lines $x = 0$ and $x = 1$. In total: $$P(Y>X) = \int_0^1\int_0^y xy\,dxdy+\int_1^2\int_0^1 xy\,dxdy.$$

[image]

To convince yourself that both ways are equally valid, calculate $P(Y>X)$ both ways and verify you get the same result (which should be $\frac 78$).

Comment: This makes sense - when getting such a question as above, would you recommend drawing a graph to quickly recognise what boundaries to use?

Comment: @strugglingmathematician, yes, that's exactly what I'd recommend, it's basic tool when doing double integrals, doesn't matter whether it's for analysis or probability. From the picture you can notice that there are two natural ways to write down the boundaries, one is like in answer by geetha290krm, but there is one more, which turns out to be more simple in this particular case. Can you see it?

Comment: 0<y<2? not sure if correct

Comment: @strugglingmathematician, that's dimensionally  incorrect, you are describing a line segment and you should describe quadrilateral.

Comment: hmm still stuck - would you mind explaining? think I might be overcoplicating it

Comment: @strugglingmathematician, I've edited the answer. Also added pictures with some "professional" arrows, which will hopefully be helpful.

Comment: Bonus question for you to think about to make sure you understand everything is to figure out over which region you integrated $xy$ so you can visually see why you got bigger end result. @strugglingmathematician

Comment: thank you so much for this! make a lot more sense now. promise final question, when drawing y = x, this is just sketching a line to identify the area "equivalent" to/ area covered the probability y > x?

Comment: also, for the first natural choice, you've integrated with respect to y and then x. i'm assuming order of integration doesnt matter with such problems? @ennar

Comment: @strugglingmathematician it's a corollary of [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%27s_theorem). And yes, $y=x$ was drawn to determine half-plane where $y>x$.

Comment: Great, everything in this topic now makes clear sense! thank you very much @ennar

Comment: @strugglingmathematician you are welcome. Remember that you can upvote answers that are useful to you (more than one) and you can accept the answer that helped you the most by clicking on check mark. Accepting an answer eventually (and I do mean eventually, you don't have to accept first answer or any until you are satisfied) is useful for the management of the website since it removes your question from the feed of unanswered question, so other questions can get more attention as well. You can also change accepted answer if better answer comes in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:$P(Y>X)=\int_0^{1}\int_0^{y}xydxdy+\int_1^{2}\int_0^{1}xydxdy$

Comment: for y, how did you deduce that limits are 0<y<1 and 1<y<2? Sorry for these probably basic questions!

Comment: As I said earlier, it is not enough to take care of $0<x<y$. This would be enough if $y<1$ because, in that case , we also have $x<1$ automatically. But if $y>1$, you have to take $x<1$ (and $x<y$ is taken care of automatically). Thumb Rule: Do not ignore any of the given inequalities. @strugglingmathematician

Comment: Makes sense, thank you!